# Player does not show up in matplotlib animations

Tags: python, matplotlib-animation

I am having troubles understanding whether is possible to plot the interactive bar in the Matplotlib animations that allows to go frame by frame, increase/reduce the speed, pause/stop, etc as in the figure in the link.
[click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMcpW.png)

The figure is shown in the examples of animation in the Matplotlib documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/animations.html

I would like it to have it in the Matplotlib gui that pop out when you run your python script. If it is possible, how can I do it? I tried changing the back-end configuration of Matplotlib, but it did not work (I tried pyqt5 and TKagg). Thank you for your help.